# How do I read these error reports of PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm starting to learn PHP so not competent enough to read these type of reports below and find a solution. An assistance would be much appreciated for me to find a solution.

I'm trying to configure PHPMailer. I have been successful in my localhost and this is the success message I get. (sorry, its a bit of text here)

```
2016-04-21 15:41:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2016-04-21 15:41:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2016-04-21 15:41:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2016-04-21 15:41:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2016-04-21 15:41:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: Y29udGFjdEBsZWFybmluZ2xpa2UuY29t 
2016-04-21 15:41:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: TWFpbHBhc3Mz 
2016-04-21 15:42:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2016-04-21 15:42:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 17:41:56 +0200 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Mohan 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: John Carter 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Subject Text 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.13 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_c1586352cd93247ad0e4bb5925de3337" 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format. 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_c1586352cd93247ad0e4bb5925de3337 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 2016-04-21 15:42:04   CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the plain text version of the email content 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_c1586352cd93247ad0e4bb5925de3337 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: Mail body in HTML 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_c1586352cd93247ad0e4bb5925de3337-- 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-04-21 15:42:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 
2016-04-21 15:42:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT Message has been sent successfully
```

However same at live server gives me an error which says;

```
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mydomain.com 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mydomain.com 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.learninglike.com 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-04-21 15:42:10 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

the PHP code I use is as follows;

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;    
$mail->isSMTP();            
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mydomain.com; mydomaincom.ipage.com; smtp.ipage.com';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             
$mail->Username = "contact@mydomain.com";                 
$mail->Password = "password";                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 25;                                   

$mail->From = "jc@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "John Carter";

$mail->addAddress("mohan@gmail.com", "Mohan");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

PS: When I change the encryption from TLS to SSL it doesn't even work in localhost. Incase if that helps in diagnosis.

Comment: Sounds as simple as your server connection settings are wrong. Check with your host(s). Or there is something blocking the port between the servers.

Comment: As starting point, hit `Ctrl`+`U` and look at the HTML source code in your browser so you can at least see *carriage returns* ;-)

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP. It's a [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) communication (something 13 years older than PHP).

Comment: It's not blocking the port - STARTTLS runs over the establish connection to port 25. The problem is that the TLS session is not being negotiated. That could be because your system doesn't like the root cert, or both ends couldn't agree a mutual cipher set. See https://doc.coker.com.au/internet/how-to-debug-smtp-with-tlsssl-and-auth/

Comment: @JonStirling you seem to be right, an issue with the server connection settings. Checked with the hosting service provider and they indeed provided an alternative to the port I have specified in my code. Thumbs up!

Comment: @symcbean I tried going through what you've suggested. However like I said my infancy with PHP still blocks me digesting that properly. Anyway trust someone from future would benefit from your comment. Thank you.

Comment: What's happenning here is outwith the realm of PHP - its happenning in SMTP land after PHP has done its job.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is PHPMailer's SMTP debug output, and it's being shown because you have `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` in your code. Setting it to 1 shows all the traffic *from* your script *to* the mail server, but it's not very useful in diagnosing your problem because you're not seeing what the server says. To get that as well, just set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`. To turn it off altogether, set it to 0.

When you set it to 2 you'll see what the problem is, and how to identify and deal with it will be described in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), which the error message you've got already links to.